# Why TortoiseGit keep asking for my user information

Tags: git, tortoisegit

TortoiseGit keeps asking my Username and email, but I have already set it.

[image]

I also already tried setting it but when I click ok it just redirect me back at the same window.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already fixed it.

I did edited ~/.gitconfig file:

```
[user]
name = 
email =
```

I deleted again the name and email, then save it and put it back again. What a weird solution.

Answer (score 1):

Git needs your **user information** for committing, including **user name** and **user email**. So, you have to config them first before commit.

Form the figure you provided, you might lack the user name.

BTW, most people usually config them at **Global** level, the steps:

1. Open TortoiseGit **Settings** dialog
2. Go **Git** page
3. Click **Global** radio box under "Config source" group box
4. Fill **Name** and **Email** text field under "User Info" group box
   (If inherit checkbox is checked, un-check them first.)
5. Push **OK** button

---

[NOTE]

TortoiseGit will show you the following message box when you go Git page first time:

[image]

> Git uses the concept of a **hierarchical** configuration.
> I.e. there are multiple levels; settings in higher levels override values in lower levels.
>
> The **Effective** tab shows you the effective values for the current scope (read-only).
>
> Select any level to see the values stored there.
> In order to change settings select a level, enter the values and select where to store to.

Answer (score 0):

In the git remote, use HTTPS repository URL instead of HTTP

[image: Git settings window]